# How to display category and price filter on layered navigation in Magento 2?

Tags: admin, magento2.2.2

I want to display category and price filter on layered navigation. I don't know how to implement this task.

Can you please help me?.

Please check my required output screenshot.

https://prnt.sc/jhjhhd

Comment: Hello Mr Dileep 

Can you please go to "Store >> product " then please say the value of "
Use in Search Results Layered Navigation" for price and category attribute

Comment: Hi, I have set values in  " Use in Search Results Layered Navigation" for price and category attribute but it's not working. In product listing page it is fine but  Filters are not displaying on the subcategory listing page.

Comment: Hi @ Emipro Technologies Pvt Ltd.I have set values in " Use in Search Results Layered Navigation" for price and category attribute but it's not working. In product listing page it is fine but Filters are not displaying on the subcategory listing page. Can you please help me?